# Выборка значений из нескольких таблиц

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

Есть три таблицы:

1. `Categories` с полями `_id`, `category`
2. `Questions` с полями `_id`, `question`, `categoryID`
3. `Answers` с полями `_id`, `answer`, `questionID`, `correct` (текстовое)

Есть вспомогательный класс `Question` с полями `questionId`, `categoryId`, `categoty`, `question`, `answer1`, `answer2`, `answer3`, `answer4`, `correctAnswer`.

Есть список `categotyList` с категориями, в котором содержатся значения Математика, География и т.д. (список может меняться в зависимости от того, какие категории выбрать в настройках).

Мне нужно в курсор выбрать все вопросы и ответы на них из категорий, которые содержатся в списке categotyList. Т.е. в курсоре в итоге должны быть поля `question`, `id` ( из таблицы `questions`), `categoty`, `id` (из таблицы `categories`), ответы для каждого вопроса из таблицы `answers` и поле `correct`.

Как составить такой запрос?

Comment: Какие варианты вы уже пробовали и что получили?

Comment: я не могу понять как в запросе указать категории из списка categotyList. Если в списке окажется 5 категорий не знаю как их указать

Comment: Типа того `where id in (1,2,3)` [SQL IN operator](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_in.asp)

Comment: не очень понял фрагмент запроса. Допустим есть 5 категорий в списке - это текстовые значения. Но я не могу знать какие именно значения в списке не перебрав его. Вот мне хочется понять какой алгоритм действий тут?

Comment: То есть вам нужно получить список id для категорий из categotyList? `Select id from Categories where category in ('Названия', 'Категорий', 'Из categotyList')`.

Comment: вам не нужно делать выборку всего сразу. Нет никакой надобности хранить в памяти кучу информации, которая возможно и не понадобится. Делайте выборки из БД только того, что нужно непосредственно в данный момент. Например, нужно вывести список категорий - запросили категории, нужены вопросы из категории, запросили эти вопросы по id категории, нужно вывести варианты ответов на текущий вопрос - запросили ответы по id вопроса и тд. Так же при работе SQLite обычно не требуются pojo-классы, работать напрямую с курсором эффективнее, хотя конечно не так удобно, как с объектом.

Comment: Мне не нужен просто список категорий. Объясню в чем дело. Я пишу приложение викторину. В ней в настройках можно выбрать вопросы каких категорий будут отображаться в викторине и если выбрано 5 категорий они попадают в список categotyList. Затем чтобы вывести сами вопросы соответствующие этим категориям я спрашиваю как составить запрос. т.е. в настройках указали категории Математика, География - они попали в categotyList. И нужно выбрать в курсор все вопросы соответствующие категориям Математика и География

Answer (score 0):

Для того, чтобы получить выборку из связанных таблиц по нескольким значениям основной таблицы нужно составить условие вида (на чистом SQL):

```
SELECT questions.question
  FROM categories, questions 
  WHERE questions.categoryID = categories._id 
    AND categories.category IN ("математика","химия")
```

Здесь, поместить в выборку значения столбца *question* таблицы *questions*, которые соответствуют значениям нескольких столбцов *category* таблицы *categories* и связаны между собой по ID. Значения "математика", "химия" и другие вы можете подставлять динамически.

Comment: Спасибо, попробую добить запрос подставив динамически категории